# Optimize SQL Query - Fetch records from two tables with multiple rows in second table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch records from two tables. Table **Spa** and Table **spa_meta**.

My Sql Query is

```
 SELECT spa_1.id as sid, spa_1.title, spa_1.doc_type, spa_1.inventory_id, inventory.unit_no as unit_no,spa_1.spa_status as spa_status, 

spa_meta.*

    FROM spa_meta

    JOIN (
       SELECT spa.*, (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM spa_meta WHERE spa_meta.spa_id = spa.id) as max_date FROM spa ) 

AS spa_1 ON spa_1.max_date = spa_meta.created_at AND spa_1.id = spa_meta.spa_id

    LEFT JOIN inventory ON spa_1.inventory_id = inventory.id  

    where spa_1.spa_status LIKE "completed%"

     group by spa_meta.spa_id
```

This query works as required but renders few hundred records in more than 10 seconds. 
I want to optimize this.

Table Definations

**SPA**  http://prntscr.com/oa30t6

**SPA_META**  http://prntscr.com/oa2zq7

**Aim**:  There are unique records in **SPA** table and in **SPA_META** there are several results for same ID in SPA. That is `spa.id = spa_meta.spa_id`.

I want to fetch the results from both tables with `Max(created_at)` date time entry from spa_meta table along with spa table row data in one row combined.

**Question** : How to reduce the execution time for this query or is there any other solution to fetch the entire row from meta table where created_at column should be `Max(created_at)`?

Comment: Not sure you have necessary indexes or not, can you post the table definitions?

Comment: @PeterHe edited. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but what i meant was for you to post the DDLs of the tables, which show the columns, keys, and indexs etc. E.g., I'd like to know whether you have index on the spa_status column in the spa table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use JOIN instead of the subquery to get the max_date, and double check indexes:

```
    SELECT spa_1.id as sid, spa_1.title, spa_1.doc_type, spa_1.inventory_id, inventory.unit_no as unit_no,spa_1.spa_status as spa_status, 
    spa_meta.*
FROM spa_meta
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT s.spa_id, MAX(s.title) AS title, MAX(s.doc_type) AS doc_type, MAX(s.inventory_id) AS inventory_id,
      MAX(s.spa_status) AS spa_status,
      MAX(sm.created_at) as max_date 
   FROM spa s
   INNER JOIN spa_meta sm
   ON s.spa_id=sm.spa_id
   WHERE s.spa_status LIKE 'completed%'
   GROUP BY s.spa_id) AS spa_1
ON spa_1.max_date = spa_meta.created_at
AND spa_1.id = spa_meta.spa_id
LEFT JOIN inventory
ON spa_1.inventory_id = inventory.id;
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterHe for your time, I concluded with a different query and it working fine.